# Bind click event on a custom google map marker (VUE JS)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**Hi everyone,**

So I'm using Vue JS on this project and what I try to achieve is a component with a full page with google map API V3. On this map there are some custom markers populated from an api’s data. Each marker is related to an event to come ( with an ID, a date, a location, a description, attendies …).
When clicking a marker, i need to display current event informations on a panel that come from right of the screen for example.

#### My problem is to bind this click event

( i can easily display console.log on click event but not interact with my vue component )

As I created programmatically these markers ( with plain JS because of google maps APi ) I can’t use @click directive on it. So guys, which solution can suits to achieve what a try to do ?

Did I miss something in the way to do with Vue JS ?

Here is a part of my code

```
Custom marker code
function CustomMarker(latlng, map, id) {
    this.latlng = latlng;
    this.id = id;
    this.setMap(map);
};


CustomMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

CustomMarker.prototype.draw = function() {

    var self = this;

    var div = this.div;

    if (!div) {

        div = this.div = document.createElement('div');
        div.dataset.index = self.id;
        div.className = 'marker js-marker';
        div.append( self.id );

        var panes = this.getPanes();
        panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
    }

    var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng);

    if (point) {
        div.style.left = (point.x - 15) + 'px';
        div.style.top = (point.y - 15) + 'px';
    }
};

CustomMarker.prototype.remove = function() {
    if (this.div) {
        this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
        this.div = null;
    }
};

CustomMarker.prototype.getPosition = function() {
    return this.latlng;
};
```

Vue code to add markers

```
created: function(){
    this.$http.get('/api/event').then( (response) => { 
        this.events = response.data;
        this.events.forEach((event) => {
            const position = new google.maps.LatLng(event.acf.location.lat, event.acf.location.lng);
            const marker = new CustomMarker(position, this.map, event.id);

            this.markers.push(marker);
            this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds.extend(position));
        });
    });
},
```

[Here is an image of what I need to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsT9o.png)

Comment: The [event namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#event) has a `addDomListener` method. Can you not use that?

Comment: Also as a side note, I would do `this.bounds.extend(position)` in the `forEach` and `this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds)` outside of the `forEach`. But that has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MrUpsidown ,  Good point for the `fitBounds` outside the loop.
I already use `addDomListener` but I was not able to interact with my Vue methods as it's not in the Vue component. But I get some help on Vue forum and the solution in my case is to use a [bus event](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)